# Unittest of angular 2 http get / observable

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, angular-cli, angular2-http

I am trying to write a unit test that tests that json i get from calling my Api validates against a mock object, but i always ends up with that the data returned from the WebApi is undefined. I believe it is because the Api returns an Observable and that hasn't been resolved when the test run.

Over that last couple of days I have googled everything i can think about related to this, but are completely stuck with no solution in sight. This being my first Angular2 project doesn't help. Anyone here that can point me in the right direction?

This is the Json i get from the WebApi

```
{
"Categories": [
    "categoryA",
    "categoryB"        
]
}
```

This is my assert. 'retrivedData' is always undefined no matter what i try

```
return siteService.getCategories({ category: 'all' }).subscribe((retrivedData) => {
    expect(retrivedData.length).toBe(2);
    expect(retrivedData[0]).toEqual(mockArrayOfCategories[0]);
    expect(retrivedData[1]).toEqual(mockArrayOfCategories[1]);
  });
```

This is my unittest (getCategories.spec.ts)

```
import { TestBed, fakeAsync, inject, tick } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { MockBackend, MockConnection } from '@angular/http/testing';
import { BaseRequestOptions, Http, Response, ResponseOptions } from '@angular/http';

import { SiteService } from './siteService.service';
import { HierarchyItem } from '../../models/HierarchyItem';
import { hasLifecycleHook } from '@angular/compiler/src/lifecycle_reflector';
import { Category } from '../../models/Category';

describe('SiteService', () => {
  let siteService: SiteService;
  let mockBackend: MockBackend;

beforeEach(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    providers: [
      SiteService,
      MockBackend,
      BaseRequestOptions,
    {
      provide: Http,
      useFactory: (backend: MockBackend, defaultOptions: BaseRequestOptions) => {
        return new Http(backend, defaultOptions);
      },
      deps: [MockBackend, BaseRequestOptions]
    }
  ]
});
});

beforeEach(inject([
  SiteService,
  MockBackend
], (_siteService: SiteService,
_mockBackend: MockBackend) => {

  siteService = _siteService;
  mockBackend = _mockBackend;
}));

afterEach(() => {
  mockBackend.verifyNoPendingRequests();
});

describe('getCategories', () => {
  it('should return an Observable<Array<Category>> containing 2 categores; A and B', fakeAsync(() => {
  // Arrange
  const mockArrayOfCategories = new Array<Category>();
  let mockCategory = new Category();
  mockCategory.name = 'categoryA';
  mockArrayOfCategories.push(mockCategory);

  mockCategory = new Category();
  mockCategory.name = 'categoryB';
  mockArrayOfCategories.push(mockCategory);

  const response = new Response(new ResponseOptions({
    body: { value: mockArrayOfCategories }
  }));
  mockBackend.connections.subscribe((connection: MockConnection) => connection.mockRespond(response));

  // Act
  const categorySubscription = siteService.getCategories({ category: 'all' });
  tick();

  // Assert
  return categorySubscription.subscribe((retrivedData) => {
    expect(retrivedData.length).toBe(2);
    expect(retrivedData[0]).toEqual(mockArrayOfCategories[0]);
    expect(retrivedData[1]).toEqual(mockArrayOfCategories[1]);
  });

}));
});
});
```

and the method being tested

```
getCategories(context: SiteContext): Observable<Array<Category>> {
    return this.http.get(routes.getCategories(context), { cache: true })
      .map((res: Response) => <Array<Category>>res.json().Categories)
      .do(data => console.log(data))
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

Comment: I'd suggest to double check your response, since you're the only person who can debug it. It's `Categories` prop in one place and `value` in another.

Comment: omg. I have not seen that. It is working now. Thank you very much estus!! :)